# grails and mysql batch processing

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, batch-processing

I'm trying to implement the advice found in [this great blog post for batch processing in grails with MySQL](http://naleid.com/blog/2009/10/01/batch-import-performance-with-grails-and-mysql/). The problem that I'm having is that inclusion of periodic calls to session.clear() in my loop causes org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException's to be thrown. There's a quote down in the comments section of the page:

> You’re second point about potentially
>   causing LIEs is absolutely true. If
>   you’re doing other things outside of
>   importing with the current thread,
>   you’ll want to make sure to reattach
>   any objects to the session after
>   you’re doing your clearing.

But how do I do that? Can anyone help me specifically understand how to "reattach any objects to the session after I'm done clearing?

I'm also interested in parallelizing the database insertion process so that I can take advantage of having a multi core processor. Can anyone provide advice on how to do that in Grails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grails has a few methods to help with this (they leverage hibernate under the covers).

If you know an object is detached, you can use the [attach](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/attach.html) method to reconnect it.

If you've made changes to the object while it was detatched, you can use [merge](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/merge.html).

If for whatever reason, you're not sure if an object is attached to the session, you can use the [link text](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/isAttached.html) method to find out if it is or isn't.

It might also be worth reviewing the Hibernate documentation on [Session](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/Session.html).

Comment: thanks for the response. Do you have any advice on how I can determine what objects need to be reattached?

Comment: @vicatu unfortunately, it can be solution dependent, it depends on what objects you might have detatched during the clear().  The other thing you could try is that rather than doing a brute force clearing of the session, you could evict the specific domain objects you're working with on the session.

Another thing that I haven't tried, is the new "withNewSession" method in GORM (http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/withNewSession.html).  It wasn't around when I wrote the post originally, but might be a better way to wrap your transaction and clean up after.